# ARC Welder Unrecognized manifest key 'arc_metadata'

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to play with a Simple ARCWelder example using Google Maps but I keep getting **Unrecognized manifest key 'arc_metadata'**.

I've done the following:

1. Created a sample Android app via Android Studio that uses Google Maps API 2. The Android app is a barebones basic app with a single MainActivity with uses SupportMapFragment. I'm very familiar with this process, and everything runs up fine on an actual device (N6), with Google Maps working correctly
2. I've taken the debug apk from point 1, and am trying to use ARC Welder to run it within Chrome.
3. As I'm using Google Play Services, I've generated an OAuth Client ID within console.developers.google.com for my project and have copied and pasted this into ARC Welder
4. I've created a package on ChromeWebStore, and have published it as private available to internal testers, and later to public but it made no difference
5. I'm running Chrome v46 and have enabled Developer Mode
6. I've taken the public key from my chrome WebStore entry, stripped out line breaks etc, and my Additional Metadata in ARCWelder looks like this:

{"crx_key":"XXXXXXX","usePlayServices":["location","maps"]}

The result under chrome://extensions:
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
Unrecognized manifest key 'arc_metadata'.

Also, TESTing my app under ARC Welder does not run up my app.

Would appreciate if anyone can offer any other suggestions?

Comment: Keep in mind that, since ARC welder is still in beta, not all Google play services are fully supported. Where are you testing your app? According to the documentation, apps will only be able to run on Chromebooks

Comment: I tried ARC 6 months ago and everything worked great.  I'm trying again now and it's no longer working.  The app doesn't start and I get that warning.  It seems like something has changed to make my app stop working where it did before.

Answer (score 1):

[Announcement](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html)
Google will no longer support Chrome App.Maybe you should try to run it on a lower version of chrome.